# Deregistering multiple LocationListeners

Tags: android, geolocation

I have the following code to request location updates from both `NETWORK_PROVIDER` and `GPS_PROVIDER`.

```
locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                                  mNetworkLocationListener);
locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                                  mGpsLocationListener);
```

I currently have a separate listener for each, but the code in the two listeners is identical, so I want to combine them into a single listener, `mLocationListener`. I will pass this to both of the two `requestLocationUpdates` calls above, so I continue to receive updates from both sources.

I will later deregister this shared listener with

```
locManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);
```

The Javadoc for `removeUpdates()` states

> Removes all location updates for the specified LocationListener.
>
> Following this call, updates will no longer occur for this listener.

So, can I safely assume that a single call to `removeUpdates()` is sufficient when I have registered the same listener twice, or do I need to call `removeUpdates()` twice too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally, the LocationManager class maps the listeners you pass to `requestLocationUpdates` to ListenerTransport objects, like this:

```
 private HashMap<LocationListener,ListenerTransport> mListeners =
        new HashMap<LocationListener,ListenerTransport>();
```

And when you call `requestLocationUpdates`, it puts that Listener that you passed into that HashMap..and since HashMaps do not allow duplicate keys, I don't believe you'll be able to share the same listener for different provider types.

That being said, since there cannot be duplicate keys, technically one call to removeUpdate is sufficient since the call to remove just removes the ListenerTransport value that the LocationListener maps to...but that doesn't really help you since you won't be able to have two different provider types with the same listener.

Comment: I called requestLocationUpdates twice (network and gps provider) with the same listener. In the onLocationChanged callback of said listener I log the provider of the given location and see both providers. Did this change with some Android version?